# Why does Google Datastore recommend manual entity ID allocation?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I would like to show users the 16 digit numeric ID of Google Datastore entities for my application. However, in the Google Datastore documentation, there is a line that states:

> "If you want to display the entity IDs to the user, and/or depend upon their order, the best thing to do is use manual allocation."

Why is it recommended that I use manual allocation if I wish to display entity IDs to users?

Answer (score 1):

It is just for better usability as 16 digits is a lot and random 16 digits look weird if a user is looking at a list, say a list of their orders. Other than that there is no issue with using them if that is fine for your users.

And also note that, after using the manual allocation you need to block that ID using datastore.AllocateIDs function in order to avoid conflicts:

> Instead of using key name strings or generating numeric IDs automatically, advanced applications may sometimes wish to assign their own numeric IDs manually to the entities they create. Be aware, however, that there is nothing to prevent Cloud Datastore from assigning one of your manual numeric IDs to another entity. The only way to avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block of IDs with the datastore.AllocateIDs function. Cloud Datastore's automatic ID generator will keep track of IDs that have been allocated with this function and will avoid reusing them for another entity, so you can safely use such IDs without conflict.